# Add row of data to ListView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview, listviewitem, itemtemplate

I'm, trying to add a row of data to a five columned list view. I have an issue with passing an array of strings into a `ListViewItem` as it does not accept the array of data. I have little experience using these views so if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, that would be great.

My listview is `lvChanges`

---

I have the following setup, is my current implementation utilizing ListView correctly?

Column 1 to 4: String

Column 5: LinkButton, CommandName="ApproveChange" - which is handled in code, however, I'm not sure how to pass an identifier for the row in *CommandArgument="?"*. I've seen many example use `<%# Eval('someKey') %>` **How does that work?** How can I pass the key? Do I need a read only property? So long as my code behind page has objects, can the attributes be directly "Eval'd"?

---

I'm trying to add items with error on the line: *"Value of type '1-dimentional array of String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemType"*

```
For i As Integer = 0 To addressList.Count
        Dim item As ListViewItem
        Dim data(5) As String
        data(0) = "Adress Change"
        data(1) = stakeholderList(i).ToString
        data(2) = stakeholderList(i).Address.ToString
        data(3) = addressList(i).ToString
        data(4) = "need the link button here!"
        item = New ListViewItem(data)    ' <-- Error
        lvChanges.Items.Add(item)
    Next
```

The data above, should go into five `<td>` tags in the `ItemTemplate`, as below

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvChanges" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="2" width="640px" border="1" ID="tbl1" runat="server">
            <tr id="Tr1" runat="server" style="background-color: #dfdbdf">
                <th runat="server"><%= Type %></th>
                <th runat="server"><%= Requester %></th>
                <th runat="server"><%= OldAddress%></th>
                <th runat="server"><%= NewAddress%></th>
                <th runat="server"><%= Decision%></th>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
          </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" >
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                    ID="btnApprove" 
                    Text="Approve" 
                    CommandName="ApproveChange"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("?") %>'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

For the `CommandArgument`, how can it so that row knows the stakeholder ID in order to complete the functionality of this piece.

Comment: `item = New ListViewItem(data)` - passing a string array is the correct syntax for WinForms.  The Web control is different

Comment: @Plutonix I see, I cannot even create a singular `ListViewItem` and pass a string into it. It will only accept `DataItem, EmptyItem, or InsertItem`

Answer (score 2):

Save it as a datatable and use the following code (make sure there are no NULLs in your dataset)

```
   Public Sub ShowDataInLvw(ByVal data As DataTable, ByVal lvw As ListView)
        lvw.View = View.Details
        lvw.GridLines = True
        lvw.Columns.Clear()
        lvw.Items.Clear()
        For Each col As DataColumn In data.Columns
            lvw.Columns.Add(col.ToString)
        Next

        For Each row As DataRow In data.Rows
            Dim lst As ListViewItem
            lst = lvw.Items.Add(row(0))
            For i As Integer = 1 To data.Columns.Count - 1
                Debug.Print(row(i).ToString)
                lst.SubItems.Add(row(i))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to add rows into a list and set data source as the list.

```
   Private result As New List(Of String())

   For i As Integer = 0 To addressList.Count
        Dim data(5) As String
        data(0) = "Adress Change"
        data(1) = stakeholderList(i).ToString
        data(2) = stakeholderList(i).Address.ToString
        data(3) = addressList(i).ToString
        data(4) = stakeholderList(i).ID
        result.Add(data)
    Next

    lvChanges.DataSource = result
    lvChanges.DataBind()
```

Then in aspx page, use `Eval()` to select the index of the elements in the list, which is a row of string data.

```
       <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server" >
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[0]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblRequester" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[1]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblOld" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[2]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblNew" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("[3]") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                    ID="btnApprove" 
                    Text="Approve" 
                    CommandName="ApproveChange"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("[4]") %>'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

ok. simple. `Eval()` is pretty straight forward